# epub.js rendition.display() does not work

Tags: javascript, epub.js

I am using epub.js in a NativeScript application.
I save a CFI as a bookmark.
When I reopen the book I call rendition.display(cfi) to return to the last place.
In many cases it just jumps to a random place which can be 10 pages away from the right place.
Does anyone have any idea what might go wrong?